# unset function vs setcookie function with past time

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie('token', '', time() - 3600, "/");
```

`setcookie` for a time in the past unsets a cookie.

```
unset($_COOKIE['token']);
```

… but so does the unset function.

Do these do the same? Which one should I use?

Comment: This question is too broad - typically you'd want to post one question per question, not multiple. See [ask] for some good guidelines. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unset should be better as it delete the cookies from browser.

also, you can delete a cookie by setting it's expiration date to the past or defining a blank value

```
setCookie('cookieName', '', -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies were invented to solve the problem "how to remember information about the user using setcookie function information destroy after some time period":

You can also delete cookies by supplying setcookie an empty value.

unset function used to destroy local or global variable, to free memory quickly using unset function.